# Changing code sample format for nasm code samples in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, nasm, github-pages

I'm using Jekyll with the [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) theme.

In a recent post I made, someone [pointed out](https://github.com/travisdowns/travisdowns.github.io/issues/3) to me that I can use nasm specific formatting with `~~~nasm` - it's good to know that nasm is a supported language!

However, the syntax highlighting is pretty ugly, look at the red glow around the square brackets:

[image: nasm code same]

It it incorrectly indicating a syntax error, due to [this bug](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/issues/1310).

Is it possible to override the style for those brackets and other aspects of the code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/master/_sass/minima.scss to **_sass/minima.scss**

Save https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/minima/master/_sass/minima/_syntax-highlighting.scss as **_sass/minima/_syntax-highlighting.scss**

You can now modify your syntax highlighting in **_sass/minima/_syntax-highlighting.scss**.

Comment: This works. Rather than actually copying the whole file, which made me nervous since I've have to check if I broke anything every time I updated minima or rouge (since I'd no longer get updates for that file) I just overrode the specific problematic css style following the advice [I got in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013314/149138).