# How to override style in imported scss file

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

My Jekyll blog's theme has a scss file with the following syntax related style in `minima.scss`:

```
.highlight {
  background: #fff;
  @extend %vertical-rhythm;

  .highlighter-rouge & {
    background: #eef;
  }

  .err   { color: #a61717; background-color: #e3d2d2 } // Error

// more stuff
```

I want to override the nested `.highlight -> .err` style only, but I don't want to set the color and bg-color attributes to anything specific, just the default. As in, I want it as if the `.err` style had never been defined in the first place.

I consume the `minima.scss` file in a `main.scss` which (which is the the actual file included in the page), like so:

```
@import "minima";

.highlight {
    .err { ???? }
}
```

This makes it easy to *add* styles, easy to *extend* styles with new attributes, and easy to *override* specific attributes of styles (since I guess the second mention takes priority), but how do I "delete" style or elements?

Comment: `all:unset` ? ... related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@import "minima";

.highlight {
  .err {
    color: unset !important;
    background-color: unset !important;
  }
}
```

Should do the trick. You can read more about ["unset"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) and ["!important"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception).

Comment: Thanks! What would the difference be versus the `inheret` suggestion in the other answer?

Comment: "The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not." - If parent doesn't have those values set (if you don't define parent's "color" and "background-color") it will choose "initial" values.
___
To sum up - a more "safe" way to do it (less chance of bugs, errors).

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I guess the only downside is lack of IE support but at this point "whatever".

Answer (score 2):

The answer that's marked correct is not the recommended way at all. In fact, it's a terrible way to override a style.

The correct way to do this:

```
@import "minima";

.highlight {
  &.err {
    color: unset;
    background-color: unset;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="highlight err"></div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference? I see an extra & and the dropping of !important.

Comment: Sure. Quick explanation. By using &.err you're appending new styles without altering styles of .highlight.

Answer (score 1):

setting the color to `inherit` will make it take it's parent element color which in this case looks to be white

Comment: Thanks! What would the difference be versus the similar `unset` suggestion in the other answer?

Comment: this may be incomplete and perhaps somebody can answer in more detail but I do not know that `unset` defaults to inherit directly from the parent once it is `unset`, it may default to _no_ background color, here you are explicitly telling it to inherit a background color from that _parent_  if one is set at that level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I chose the other one because I ended up using `unset` and it came first, and I can choose only one, but I consider this one just as good.